# Can Disney+ require me to disclose my age and gender in order to continue streaming?

Tags: california, privacy

I just received this email a few moments ago:

> ## Disney+
>
> ### Provide your birthdate and gender to keep streaming
>
> Disney+ now requires additional information from the primary account holder, including your birthdate and what best describes your gender. To avoid any interruption to your streaming, please update your account with this information before December 8, 2022.

Screenshot:

[image]

And [they say](https://help.disneyplus.com/csp?id=csp_article_content&sys_kb_id=a3f7af9f87c791d44e3f7557cebb35d0):

> Disney+ is also requiring what best describes your gender. This information will be used to personalize your experience, which may include ads, and in other ways consistent with our Privacy Policy

---

As per my understanding of the CRPA, the section on Data Minimization ([as reported by this website](https://www.osano.com/articles/california-privacy-laws-ccpa-cpra)) says:

> Businesses must only collect and retain what’s “reasonably necessary” and “proportionate” to the intended purpose.

I already have an account in good-standing with Disney+ for about a year now - I'm sure they already know I'm a legal adult for the reasonable purpose of controlling age-restricted content within their streaming service - and to require a statement of gender disclosure is *just odd* - so I cannot fathom how they can hold my access to their service for ransom at the price of my personal information.

Comment: I can see that they need your age (what makes you believe they know it?), but why they need your gender confuses me, too.

Comment: "What best describes your gender" might be to properly fill out the paperwork. As in "Mr/Ms/Mss" or something.

Comment: @Trish Airlines and conferences usually ask for an addressing choice their - Mr, Mrs, Dr, and a few others sometimes

Comment: @ZOMVID-21 Airlines require your gender in case of crash. They actually are entitled to know it.

Comment: @PMF they said why then want it. To target ads. Whether that is effective or just stereotyping is another story.

Comment: What ransom? You can choose not to do business with them and stop paying your monthly fee.

Comment: From the Disney+ website answering "Why does Disney+ need my birthdate and gender?": "Disney+ is also requiring what best describes your gender. This information will be used to personalize your experience, which may include ads, and in other ways consistent with our Privacy Policy. This information is not required for profiles associated with birthdates under 13, and you may elect “Prefer not to say” in lieu of an identification."

Comment: So they are not allowed to force you to tell them your gender, but they can force you to tell them that you don’t want to tell them your gender :-) Now seriously, for “age” can you tell them “above 18” or “above 21”? I can’t see any reason for them knowing that you are 57, for example.

Answer (score 8):

Disney's [help page on this](https://help.disneyplus.com/csp?id=csp_article_content&sys_kb_id=a3f7af9f87c791d44e3f7557cebb35d0#6) says

> ##### I don’t want to provide my birthdate or gender. What can I do?
>
> Providing a birthdate is required for all Disney+ accounts/profiles while a gender is required for all accounts/profiles over the age of 13. Note that for gender submission, you may elect “Prefer not to say.” If you do not wish to provide your birthdate or gender, you may cancel your account by visiting your Account page or by contacting Disney+ Support.

It's reasonable to provide proof of age: COPPA in the US requires it to protect those under 13. And you don't have to give them your gender.

Comment: COPPA only requires evidence you are over 13.  They don't need to store an actual birthdate.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica This is true: but then you don't have to give them your actual birthdate either. You're only required to provide **a** birthdate. Disney's help text here suggests they provide services to under-13s, so a birthdate is needed to ensure the right services are provided.

Comment: Can a primary account holder be under 13, or for that matter under 18? Under the impression that those under 18 can not enter into contractual agreements.

Comment: I've no idea. The point is that wanting to know your age is perfectly reasonable, and you don't have to reveal your gender if you don't want to.

Comment: @paulj that impression is incorrect, [at least in some jurisdictions](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=minor+contract).

Comment: @paulj In the US, someone under the age of 13 can have an account with their parent's permission. Someone between the age 13 and 18 can have an account, but can cancel the contract any time they want.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @AndrewLeach as far as that answer goes, but would add an additional point. As the question notes:

> Businesses must only collect and retain what’s “reasonably necessary”
> and “proportionate” to the intended purpose.

But, the intended purpose can legitimately be to use information gathered to facilitate advertising on the Disney+ platform, or another platform (either affiliated with Disney+ or otherwise), unless the privacy policy of Disney+ dictates otherwise.

The "intended purpose" does not have to be simply to facilitate the user's intended purpose.

I suspect that gathering information about users to facilitate targeted advertising is part of the business model of the platform.